# Android - ArrayList size always return 0

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am getting places with Google Maps and retrofit and adding them in a list. I want to collect all places in a list, I did it like in the below but `allItem` list size returns always 0, I can not figure out why, am I missing something?. Can anyone help me?

My Globals

```
ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> myList;
ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> allItems;
```

Button click function

```
 menuOption1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myList = new ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean>();
                allItems = new ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean>();

                allItems.addAll(selectAllFrom("restaurant", myList));
                allItems.addAll(selectAllFrom("cafe", myList));
                allItems.addAll(selectAllFrom("bar", myList));

                Log.v("Size", "Places List size : " + allItems.size() + "");
            }
        });
```

SelectAllFrom function

```
private ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> selectAllFrom(final String type, final ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> list) {

        // Creating an object of our api interface
        ApiService myApi = RetroClient.getApiService();

        // Calling JSON
        Call<MapData> call = myApi.getNearbyPlaces(type, mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mLastLocation.getLongitude(), PROXIMITY_RADIUS);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MapData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MapData> call, Response<MapData> response) {

                Log.v("Response Code", "Response Code is : " + response.code());

                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    try {
                        // This loop will go through all the results
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {
                            addToList(list, response.body().getResults().get(i));
                        }

                        Log.v(type, "List Size : " + list.size() + "");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something work wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MapData> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return  list;

    }
```

and last, here is my addToList function

```
void addToList(ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> myList, MapData.ResultsBean item){
    if(!myList.contains(item))
        myList.add(item);
}
```

This is my logcat, allItem size always return 0

```
V/Size: Places List size : 0
V/restaurant: List Size : 20
V/bar: List Size : 21
V/cafe: List Size : 41
```

Comment: You create two new empty lists at `menuOption1.setOnClickListener` when you use new, and then you print the size of places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback in `call.enqueue(...)` will be executed asynchronously. This means it can be called at an arbitrary time in the future.

This means what your code is doing is:

- Call `selectAllFrom`
- Call `call.enqueue(...)`
- Return `list`, which is still empty at this point
- Add the empty list to `allItems`
- [At some later point] Calls `addToList` in the callback

This is simply a case of trying to use an asynchronous resource synchronously. It is actually a race condition since the asynchronous callback might be called when `selectAllFrom` for another value is being called since it uses a shared `myList`, resulting in a wrong answer.

When using asynchronous resources (like Retrofit's calls) you either need to wait for a value (`call.execute()`) and deal with the fact that it freezes the UI or fully commit to the asynchronous ways of doing things.

EDIT: Also be aware that Android has strict requirements about threads and manipulating the UI. `Toast.makeText()` in the callback will probably cause exceptions since the callback does not get executed on the UI thread.

Comment: I see, so I must wait until retrofit response finish, then call list, am I right?

Comment: Until retrofit returns the list will be empty. How you deal with the asynchronous behavior is your decision as a developer